# Set cookie in HTTP domain using HTTPS domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, cookies, https

I am sucked into a scenario where I have to set a cookie in the **HTTP** domain via the **HTTPS** domain.

I have a backend service running on **HTTPS**. eg:  `https://api.example.com`
My front end is running on **HTTP**. eg: `http://fe.example.com`

The frontend will trigger an API call in the login process and the backend needs to validate the data and set a cookie if the data is valid.

Right now, the cookie is sending in the response but it says it cannot set that cookie as those domains are different (due to HTTP and HTTPS).

Is there any way to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that's possible ... that's just as possible as setting a cookie for google.com from microsoft.com :p

Comment: Bad application design.